# Is there a way in phpunit that I could possibly assert two values for a key in an array?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

```
$array = [a => '1',
 b => '2']
```

For example, I want to check if a was either 1 or 3. I thought using this would work.

```
$this->assertThat(
    $this->assertContains('1',$array),
    $this->logicalOr(
        $this->assertContains('3',$array)
));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to assert that `$array["a"]` ("I want to check if a...") contains 1 or 3, then this will work:

```
$array = ["a" => "1", "b" => "2"];
$this->assertThat($array["a"],
    $this->logicalOr(
        $this->equalTo("1"),
        $this->equalTo("3")
));
```